# React native manually rejecting a promise

Tags: react-native, promise

I am basically trying to wrap the React Native GPS feature into a Promise.
When I reach the failure callback of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` I want to manually reject a Promise.

Here the relevant code:

```
var p = new Promise();

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
     (position) => { ... all good here ... },
     (error) => {
         // trying to reject manually a Promise
         p.reject(error);
     }
);
```

Problems:

1. If I don't pass any function in the Promise arguments I get `not a function` error on the first line
2. If I pass a function I get `undefined is not a function evaluating p.reject`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was confusing Promise with an Angular-like deferred promise.

A working way is to wrap the GPS function into a Promise like so:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
         resolve('All good');
      },
      (error) => {
         reject(error);
      }
   );
});
```

Comment: Promisification will simplify - maybe as simple as `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPositionAsync = () => new Promise(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition.bind(navigator.geolocation));`